# What is the best approach to handle session timeouts in struts2

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2, session-timeout

I have a struts2 app and I need to handle the session-timeout in the logged section.

What I have in mind is to use an Interceptor class :

```
public class SessionInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
  @Override
  public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
      Map<String,Object> session = invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();
      if(session.isEmpty())
          return "session";
      return invocation.invoke();
  }
}
```

In my struts.xml :

```
<struts>
  <interceptor name="session" class="org.app.struts.interceptor.SessionInterceptor" />  
  <interceptor name="admin" class="org.app.struts.interceptor.AdminInterceptor" />

  <interceptor-stack name="adminStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="session"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="admin"/>
  </interceptor-stack>

  <action name="doaction" class="org.app.class" method="doAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="adminStack" />
    <result name="success">page.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
    <result name="session">sessionexpired.jsp</result>
  </action>
</struts>
```

Is there a better approach ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://nickcoblentz.blogspot.com/2008/11/page-level-access-controls-in-struts-2.html
and in web.xml:

```
<session-config>  
        <session-timeout>  
            30  
        </session-timeout>  
    </session-config>
```

this is for 30 minutes